# How to remove ads on utube player

Tags: actionscript-3, youtube-api, ads

I'm making the flash air app with Youtube Player API.
One day, I saw the app playing the video that ads was removed on Youtube Player.
But I guess the app is not a flash air app.
Is it possible to remove the ads on Youtube Player in the app?
If it is possible, please let me know how to remove the ads when the video is playing on Youtube Player.

Answer (score 0):

i always think it can be done by just extracting the streaming url 
then you can show it without ads
but i never had the time to do it